# Java using jProgressBar within loop

Tags: java, netbeans, jprogressbar

i build an Application and i have a button do a lot of things when i press it the application is freeze it for some second. So i just want put a jProgressBar here is my code :

```
String s="";
long l=System.currentTimeMillis();

for(int k=0;k<jTable3.getRowCount();k++)
{
    s=jTable3.getValueAt(k, 0).toString();
    myFunction(s);
}

long l2=System.currentTimeMillis();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "We are done in just "+(l2-l)+" MS");
```

Any help or suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is perform your lengthy/taxing operations on another thread, and then, from that thread, adjust the value of your `JProgressBar`. The progress will then be visible.

[Some information on concurrency and threads.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)